# php - mysqli to pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello everyone I'm completely new to mysqli and PDO. I tried to convert my msqli code to PDO but I keep getting errors. Can someone please help me? the error is like when i click on post, nothing happens and I searched everywhere how to convert from msqli to pdo and I converted some of them but it still doesn't work

```
       <?php 
  $databaseHost = 'localhost';
$databaseName = 'test';
$databaseUsername = 'test'; 
$databasePassword = 'pass';
try { 

    $dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host={$databaseHost};dbname={$databaseName}", $databaseUsername, $databasePassword);

    $dbConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
  if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (name, comment) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$comment}')";
    if ($result = $dbConn->query($sql)) {
      $id = $link->insert_id;
      $saved_comment = '<div class="comment_box">
            <span class="delete" data-id="' . $id . '" >delete</span>
            <span class="edit" data-id="' . $id . '">edit</span>
            <div class="display_name">'. $name .'</div>
            <div class="comment_text">'. $comment .'</div> 
        </div>';
      echo $saved_comment;
    }else {
      echo "Error: ".($dbConn);
    }
    exit();
  }
  // delete comment fromd database
  if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id=" . $id;
    ($dbConn->prepare($sql));
    exit(); 
  }
  if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $sql = "UPDATE comments SET name='{$name}', comment='{$comment}' WHERE id=".$id;
    if ($dbConn->prepare($sql)) {
        $id =($dbConn);
        $saved_comment = '<div class="comment_box">
          <span class="delete" data-id="' . $id . '" >delete</span>
          <span class="edit" data-id="' . $id . '">edit</span>
          <div class="display_name">'. $name .'</div>
          <div class="comment_text">'. $comment .'</div>
      </div>';
      echo $saved_comment;
    }else {
      echo "Error: ". ($dbConn);
    }
    exit();
  }

  // Retrieve comments from database
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
  $result = $dbConn->prepare($sql); 
  $comments = '<div id="display_area">'; 
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $comments .= '<div class="comment_box">
          <span class="delete" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" >delete</span>
          <span class="edit" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '">edit</span>
          <div class="display_name">'. $row['name'] .'</div>
          <div class="comment_text">'. $row['comment'] .'</div>
      </div>';
  }
  $comments .= '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: so what are those errors?

Comment: this is a typo question.

Answer (score 1):

You used `->prepare()`, but did not use `->execute()`.

Documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Right; however those can merely be replaced with `query()` as they did for other queries. They assumed that by "preparing", that it would help against an sql injection, which doesn't and are (still) open to an sql injection.